# Why does avr-gcc add "push r1" instructions to the start of a function?

Tags: assembly, avr, avr-gcc

I was looking at the produced assembly of some code I had written after compiling with `avr-gcc`. Specifically I compiled with the `-Os` option. Overall the output is what I expect, but what I cannot understand is the instruction `push r1` being emitted. Even stranger is the fact that the complementary instruction at the end of the function is `pop r0`. So the value of `r1` is being saved but it appears to be restored to `r0`

Per the documentation here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Register_Layout

The register `r1` always containers zero, but a function may use the register if it restores it. Restoring it would be `ldi r1, 0x0`, there would be no need for a push, pop from my understanding.

Here's an example of the C code and disassembly of the compiled version. It is compiled with `-Os`. It's a bit long but I had to make a large function to get the compiler to emit this.

C code:

```
void mqtt_create_connect(mqtt_parser *p, mqtt_connect_config *cfg){
  uint8_t idx = 0;
  p->buffer[idx++] = MQTT_CTRL_CONNECT << 4;
  idx++; // skip remaining length for now
  p->buffer[idx++] = 0x0;
  p->buffer[idx++] = 0x4;
  p->buffer[idx++] = 'M';
  p->buffer[idx++] = 'Q';
  p->buffer[idx++] = 'T';
  p->buffer[idx++] = 'T';
  p->buffer[idx++] = 0x04; // protocol level 3.1.1
  p->buffer[idx++] = 
    MQTT_CONNECT_FLAG_CLEAN_SESSION;
  push_uint16_t(p, cfg->keepAliveInterval, &idx);
  push_charptr(p, cfg->clientIdentifier, &idx);
  p->bufferIdx = idx;

  // fill in remaining length
  p->buffer[1] = p->bufferIdx - 2;
}
```

Disassembly:

```
0000006a <mqtt_create_connect>:
  6a:   0f 93           push    r16
  6c:   1f 93           push    r17
  6e:   cf 93           push    r28
  70:   df 93           push    r29
  72:   1f 92           push    r1
  74:   cd b7           in      r28, 0x3d       ; 61
  76:   de b7           in      r29, 0x3e       ; 62
  78:   8c 01           movw    r16, r24
  7a:   fb 01           movw    r30, r22
  7c:   80 e1           ldi     r24, 0x10       ; 16
  7e:   d8 01           movw    r26, r16
  80:   11 96           adiw    r26, 0x01       ; 1
  82:   8c 93           st      X, r24
  84:   11 97           sbiw    r26, 0x01       ; 1
  86:   13 96           adiw    r26, 0x03       ; 3
  88:   1c 92           st      X, r1
  8a:   13 97           sbiw    r26, 0x03       ; 3
  8c:   84 e0           ldi     r24, 0x04       ; 4
  8e:   14 96           adiw    r26, 0x04       ; 4
  90:   8c 93           st      X, r24
  92:   14 97           sbiw    r26, 0x04       ; 4
  94:   9d e4           ldi     r25, 0x4D       ; 77
  96:   15 96           adiw    r26, 0x05       ; 5
  98:   9c 93           st      X, r25
  9a:   15 97           sbiw    r26, 0x05       ; 5
  9c:   91 e5           ldi     r25, 0x51       ; 81
  9e:   16 96           adiw    r26, 0x06       ; 6
  a0:   9c 93           st      X, r25
  a2:   16 97           sbiw    r26, 0x06       ; 6
  a4:   94 e5           ldi     r25, 0x54       ; 84
  a6:   17 96           adiw    r26, 0x07       ; 7
  a8:   9c 93           st      X, r25
  aa:   17 97           sbiw    r26, 0x07       ; 7
  ac:   18 96           adiw    r26, 0x08       ; 8
  ae:   9c 93           st      X, r25
  b0:   18 97           sbiw    r26, 0x08       ; 8
  b2:   19 96           adiw    r26, 0x09       ; 9
  b4:   8c 93           st      X, r24
  b6:   19 97           sbiw    r26, 0x09       ; 9
  b8:   82 e0           ldi     r24, 0x02       ; 2
  ba:   1a 96           adiw    r26, 0x0a       ; 10
  bc:   8c 93           st      X, r24
  be:   1a 97           sbiw    r26, 0x0a       ; 10
  c0:   80 81           ld      r24, Z
  c2:   91 81           ldd     r25, Z+1        ; 0x01
  c4:   1b 96           adiw    r26, 0x0b       ; 11
  c6:   9c 93           st      X, r25
  c8:   1b 97           sbiw    r26, 0x0b       ; 11
  ca:   9c e0           ldi     r25, 0x0C       ; 12
  cc:   99 83           std     Y+1, r25        ; 0x01
  ce:   1c 96           adiw    r26, 0x0c       ; 12
  d0:   8c 93           st      X, r24
  d2:   62 81           ldd     r22, Z+2        ; 0x02
  d4:   73 81           ldd     r23, Z+3        ; 0x03
  d6:   ae 01           movw    r20, r28
  d8:   4f 5f           subi    r20, 0xFF       ; 255
  da:   5f 4f           sbci    r21, 0xFF       ; 255
  dc:   c8 01           movw    r24, r16
  de:   0e 94 00 00     call    0       ; 0x0 <push_charptr>
  e2:   89 81           ldd     r24, Y+1        ; 0x01
  e4:   f8 01           movw    r30, r16
  e6:   ef 5b           subi    r30, 0xBF       ; 191
  e8:   ff 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFF       ; 255
  ea:   80 83           st      Z, r24
  ec:   82 50           subi    r24, 0x02       ; 2
  ee:   f8 01           movw    r30, r16
  f0:   82 83           std     Z+2, r24        ; 0x02
  f2:   0f 90           pop     r0
  f4:   df 91           pop     r29
  f6:   cf 91           pop     r28
  f8:   1f 91           pop     r17
  fa:   0f 91           pop     r16
  fc:   08 95           ret
```

What is the purpose of the `push r1` and the `pop r0`?

Comment: possibly stack alignment, to push/pop dummy registers?  I didn't really look at the code, bug modern clang does that on x86-64.

Comment: It seems to be to implement this rule: "After the function prologue, the frame pointer will point one byte below the stack frame, i.e. Y+1 points to the bottom of the stack frame." But I have no idea why it wouldn't be better for Y+0 to point to the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two tricks here.

At first, gcc needs to reserve one-byte place on stack — for `uint8_t idx;`
Stack pointer need to be decremented and saved back to `SPH:SPL`. But this two-`out` operation can be interrupted with catastrophic results. So it must be wrapped on by `cli`/`sei` pair — extra code and time.
Pushing of *any* register gives the same result atomically and using short code.

Second: as You note, by avr-gcc/avr-libc convention, `r1` is `__zero_reg__`, assumed to be always zero in any C code.
So, `push r1` not only reserves space for `idx` but also initializes it by `0`.

`pop r0` in function epilogue restores stack pointer. By mentioned convention, `r0` is `__temp_reg__`, temporary register that can be clobbered by any C code. So compiler can destroy its content at any time.

p.s. The function does not change `r1`, so that no `r1` restoring needed.